# JSON Definitions Using Internally Defined Variables

Tags: javascript, json, object, definition

I am trying to create a JSON object to store some parameters for a program.  Some of the parameters need to be calculated from others as they are being defined.  I would like to do this within the object definition but maybe this is not possible

```
var params = {
        a: 50,
        b: 70,
        c: this.a+this.b
    }
```

**Result**

What happens

```
>params.c
NaN
```

What I wished happened

```
>params.c
120
```

**Edit**

After doing some further reading, I think I am using Object Literal Notation instead of JSON.

Comment: Note this is not JSON, it is a object literal. [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @PatrickEvans Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use this approach:**

To avoid re-calculation, use the function `Object.assign`.

> The `get` syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.

```js
var params = {
  a: 50,
  b: 70,
  get c() {
    console.log('Called!');
    return this.a + this.b;
  }
};

console.log(params.c); // Prints 120 then Called!
console.log(params.c); // Prints 120 then Called!

var params = Object.assign({}, {
  a: 50,
  b: 70,
  get c() {
    console.log('Called from function Object.assign!');
    return this.a + this.b;
  }
});

params.a = 1000; // To illustrate.

console.log(params.c); // Prints 120
console.log(params.c); // Prints 120
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

## Resources

- [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)
- [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Comment: This is ok but I would like to avoid calculating each parameter every time it is called.

Comment: @Cole the attributes `a` and `b` will change in time?

Comment: @Cole see the updated answer.

Comment: No, this was intended for initialization purposes.  Good to know that you can make it dynamic if needed though!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would create constants (since magic numbers are the devil), but this is an overly-simplistic example:

```
const FIFTY = 50;
const SEVENTY = 70;
var params = {
  a: FIFTY,
  b: SEVENTY,
  c: FIFTY + SEVENTY
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend doing is starting with an object that does not contain `c`, and taking the calculation outside of the object. Once the calculation has occurred, simply add the sum back to the object as a new key/value pair:

```js
var params = {
  a: 50,
  b: 70,
}

var sum = 0;

for (var el in params) {
  if (params.hasOwnProperty(el)) {
    sum += params[el];
  }
}

params['c'] = sum;
console.log(params);
```